# How to ensure that Infopath 2010 is in online mode?

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services, office-integration, list-template

Tried to search internet but could not find it.
I was given Infopath (.xsn) form which I open from file system and get:

[image]

- *"The query cannot be run for the following DataObject: Region
  InfoPath cannot run the specified query.
  Some form data cannot be retrieved because InfoPath is operating in offline mode. Form elements, such as drop-down lists, may be blank. Ensure that you have network connectivity and that InfoPath is in online mode"*

How to ensure that Infopath 2010 is in online mode?
What is offline mode of Infopath?

**Update**:
The forms are files .xsn from download for book [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frTDj.jpg)

- 0672333422_Content.zip\DownLoadable Content\Forms*.xsn

The funny for me thing is that all starts working if to copy to and open files exactly in:

- C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\
  but not to its subdirectory!

Well, kind of because it shows the warning:

- **"Infopath Editor Security Notice**

  **Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern

  Security Warning: This form may use your identity to connect to data sources"**

[image]

Also in Windows Explorer it is "My Documents" while it is really "Documents"

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frTDj.jpg)
STEVEN MANN. InfoPath® with SharePoint® 2010 HOW-TO
 by Sams Publishing

Comment: Is this Infopath form published on a list or are you just trying to preview the form using Infopath form designer ?

Comment: Additionally, does your form refer to some external list columns or database to populate form fields ?

Comment: Well, thanks, I resolved the issue before seeing your comments. See my answer. Still I did not (bother to) understand quite clearly so any further explanations are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question because the both the blocking and the warnings gone after I enabled following options for Infopath Form Services.

In "Sharepoint 2010 Central administration" --> General Application Settings" --> Infopath Forms Services --->  "Configure Infopath Forms Services"   I enabled:

- Allow users to browser-enable form templates
- Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users
- Allow embedded SQL authentication
- Allow user form templates to use authentication information contained in data connection files
- Allow cross-domain data access for user form templates that use connection settings in a data connection file

[image: Configure Infopath Forms Services]

And in Central Administration --> General Application Settings --> Configure InfoPath Forms Services Web Service Proxy:

- **Enable InfoPath Forms Services Web service proxy**
  Use the proxy for data connections between InfoPath Forms Services forms and Web services. The data connections must be defined in universal data connection (UDC) files and they must be enabled to use a proxy
- **Enable InfoPath Forms Services Web service proxy for user forms**
  Use the proxy for data connections in user forms

[image]

Not sure (and do not care) what of them specifically has solved the issues. But they gone for good

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing Internet Option/Browsing History[image]